# Unreal mouseX and mouseY only up and down

Tags: controls, mouse, unreal-engine4, blueprint

I just start working in unreal engine and i have very strange problem.I working on unreal 4.20 and I try implement mouse sensitivity in blueprints. When I add MouseY to inputs then when I move mouse to left and right camera go up and down.

Project settings: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIqZu.jpg

Blueprint
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dijWB.jpg

When I remove "InputAxis Turn" mouse work ok. What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For "InputAxis Turn" , it should be connected to "Add Controller yaw input" instead of pitch, that was the mistake.

You connected Add pitch controller twice on both axis, that doesnt make sense . and it will treat the X-axis as Y-axis in term of input.